# Возможно ли анимировать кластеризацию объектов на карте при зуме?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Яндекс карта построена на "objectManager", для кластеризации использую макет метки PieChart. Появилась "хотелка" анимировать кластеризацию - "чтобы кластеры объединялись плавно". (как на сайте "этажи" с картой 2gis). Подскажите есть ли возможность сделать такое на Яндекс карте и как?

Answer (score 1):

В API нет встроенных методов для анимации маркеров.